# bundle.js not loaded successfully in static html files but refer to

Tags: html, asp.net-core, nginx, web

I have a static index.html in wwwroot of an asp.net core web project which useStaticFiles:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body>
    ...
    <script src="~/scripts/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>    
</html>
```

After web application published. the bundle.js could not load successfully, after F12 in Chrome and found browser trying to load js by url:
[https://127.0.0.1:5001/~/scripts/bundle.js](https://127.0.0.1:5001/%7E/scripts/bundle.js)

Please help a clue. thanks!
By the way, the web application run fluently without such errors locally.

Comment: Hi @cc5zhenhua, where is your scripts folder located? If it locates in wwwroot/scripts/bundle.js, just change your script src to:`<script src="scripts/bundle.js"></script>`.

Comment: Yes, it locates under wwwroot/scripts . Thanks for your response. After an investigation looks more like an nginx issue. As I set a local path which proxied to port 5001 where  hosted the static html&js files...

Answer (score 0):

It's actually an Nginx configuration issue. `https://www.***.com/subpath1/test.html.`
nginx proxied subpath1 to local port 5588 where test.html hosted in.
In test.html `<script src="bundle.js">` didn't refer to
`https://www.***.com/subpath1/bundle.js` as expected but `https://www.***.com/bundle.js`
So update test.html src attribute `src="subpath1/bundle.js"` solved the problem.
Thanks all~